# Quarkus error after compiling native with Jaeger Tracing

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus, graalvm, jaeger

I am trying to compile an application in Quarkus Native and monitor it using Jaeger Traicing, however, I am encountering a problem that when compiling it is taking the wrong url and not the one I should use to work with opentracing:

Example application.properties file:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:tracing:oracle:thin:@172.28.2.134:1522/IVR
quarkus.datasource.username=${USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.datasource.password=${PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8082}
quarkus.http.ssl-port=${PORT-SSl:8083}
quarkus.jaeger.service-name=find-puk-code-tracing
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=const
quarkus.jaeger.sampler-param=1
quarkus.jaeger.endpoint=${URL_JAEGER:http://10.161.169.24:14268/api/traces}
quarkus.native.add-all-charsets=true
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/api/FindPukCodeBS/swagger-ui
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api/FindPukCodeBS/swagger
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

Locally it works wonderfully, but when I deploy at the kubernetes level it is not taking the url correctly, as follows::

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:tracing:oracle:thin:@172.28.2.134:1522/IVR
```

In the logs that appear to me it seems to take the url without the word tracing, however as you can see at the log level it prints the url that is being passed in the application.properties:

[image]

That could be happening? I don't understand, and I don't have the value burned anywhere, I'm taking it directly from the application.properties.

Comment: I vaguely remember someone reporting a similar issue on Github. Have you checked?

Comment: Didn't get a response anywhere.

Comment: can you put a reproducer in github ?